# Changing status bar position

Tags: c++, winapi, statusbar

I'm trying to make a map editor, and I'm loosely basing it off of the Game Maker map editor. One of the things I like about it is the object panel on the left-hand side and a status bar between the end of it and the right-hand side of the window. Here's a picture:

[image: Game Maker's map editor]

I can't figure out how that was done. I assume the creator somehow got the statusbar to change its position and width, but nothing I do can change it. I was also thinking that the left area is some special window/control that I don't know about. How do I get this?

Comment: There are some good answers to your previous questions. How come you haven't accepted any?

Comment: Now I have - I didn't know you were supposed to

Comment: Mm, only 25%. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by telling the status bar not to reposition itself, then positioning it yourself.

The former means altering the status bar's styles. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - particularly CCS_NOMOVEX.

The latter means moving the status bar window in response to WM_SIZE messages sent to the window the status bar is in (usually your main window).

Comment: Thanks! That worked, after a little playing around with the various styles.